# Reverse function in C produces word then rubbish

Tags: c, string, char, reverse

I'm implementing a function that reverses a string in C. This is my code:

```
void reverse(char *str) {
    int strlength = strlen(str);
    int len = strlength+1;
    char rev[len];      
    int i = 0;      
    while(strlength > 0) {
        rev[i++] = str[--strlength];
    }
    strcpy(str, rev);
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
        printf("[%s <==> ", argv[i]); 
        reverse(argv[i]);
        printf("%s].. ",argv[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

This is what happens when I try it on the words: `john`, `carl`, `cat`, `apple`, `friday`:

```
[john <==> nhojِ¶@]
[n <==> n↨>]
[cat <==> tac]
[apple <==> elppa¶@]
[ <==> C↨>]
```

Comment: `reverse` doesn't zero-terminate `rev` before `strcpy`. Try putting `rev[i] = '\0';` after your `while` loop in `reverse`.

Comment: Might as well `memcpy(str, rev, len);`, potentially faster.

Answer (score 3):

You do not  zero-terminate the string in `rev[]` , put

```
rev[i] = '\0';
```

after the while loop

Comment: Only the second part is right (about null termination).

Comment: Or ` rev[strlength] = '\0';` before the while loop, null terminating the `rev` string.

Answer (score 3):

After this loop

```
while(strlength > 0)
{
    rev[i++] = str[--strlength];
}
```

insert additional statement

```
rev[i] = '\0';
```

Your function is too complicated. I would write it like

```
char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

In this case function main also could be written simpler. For example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i;

   for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
   {
      printf( "[%s <==> ", argv[i] ); 
      printf( "%s].. \n", reverse( argv[i] ) );
   }
}
```

Take into account that though usually reverse functions have return type void string functions have their own convention on the return type. Usually they return a pointer to a string.

Comment: @sp2danny It is better when such pronitive functions do not call other functions. That is that they would not require additional headers

Comment: @sp2danny However I agree with you that it wpuld be easier to read it with swap.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
  int j = strlen(str) - 1 ;
  int len = (j + 1) / 2 ;

  int i ;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
     char c = str[i] ;
     str[i] = str[j] ;
     str[j] = c ;
     j-- ;
  }
}
```

Furthermore I'm not sure if the strings pointed by the pointers in `argv` can be modified on all platforms. If not, the main function should be something like this:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buffer[30];

  int i;
  for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
  {
      strcpy(buffer, argv[i]) ;
      printf("[%s <==> ", argv[i]); 
      reverse(buffer);
      printf("%s].. ",buffer);
      printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggest `while (strlength > 0)` instead of `while(strlength / 2 + 1 > 0)`.  `while(strlength / 2 + 1 > 0)` generates negative indexes for `str[]`.

Comment: OK, my solution was completly wrong, but now it's OK.